# WPF Binding with a Border

Tags: wpf, binding, border

I have a group of borders that make up a small map. Ideally I'd like to be able to bind the border's background property to a property in a custom list and when that property changes it changes the background.

The tricky thing is, I have to do this in code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [FrameworkElement.SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.setbinding.aspx) method:

```
myBorder.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty, "CurrentBackground");
```

or, if you need sources and converters and things:

```
myBorder.SetBinding(Border.BackgroundProperty,
  new Binding(somePath) {
    Source = something,
    Converter = new WonderConverter()
    // etc.
  });
```